# How do I create circular polygon pour cutout in Cadsoft EAGLE?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, layout

I would like to have a cutout without copper within a polygon pour.  I tried to draw  a circle on the top layer but to no avail.

Comment: Look, my non-volatile memory is precious and better be used to store bootloader configs, make file commands, C, C++, OC C# keywords, java encapsulation concepts etc. etc. I couldn't bother less to spend a rising edge on learning how to use SE features so no thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to draw your primary copper pour on the top (or bottom) layer, and the circular cutout on the appropriate Restrict layer: tRestict (top) or bRestrict (bottom).

The copper polygon will not extend onto the restrict-layer feature.

Make sure the copper pour is a polygon, not just a "rectangle"!  The primitive rectangle and circle features are simply static shapes which do not automatically adjust to the design constraints.

Confusingly, there is also a vRestrict layer, which actually forbids vias, not copper features.

Comment: @MattCox Glad to help! It looks like you're new to the Stack. Welcome!  If you're satisfied with an answer, please mark it "Accepted" by clicking the checkbox under the voting buttons.  It helps keep our database clean (and gives some rep) :)

Comment: Voted. No I'm not new to stack at all. I'm a regular to stackoverflow, which is a cesspool of elitism. couple of asshole mods don't even look at what you ask before dishing out "Oh let me guess, you are de-referencing a null pointer" or "let me guess, you tried to wrap a 64bit long with a 32bit wrapper". And then I got blocked, and then I had to register a new account.  Elec SE so far has been helpful.

Comment: @MattCox Thanks for the vote! I hope it all works out better for you this time around...